Mise : Cannot install Ruby@3.2.1 on Mac M3
I cannot install Ruby@3.2.1 on my mac M3 (arm64 arch). I get the following error when I type mise install ruby@3.2.1 :
==> Installing ruby-3.2.1...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
ruby-build: using libyaml from homebrew
-> ./configure "--prefix=$HOME/.local/share/mise/installs/ruby/3.2.1" --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --enable-shared --with-readline-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/readline --with-libyaml-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml --with-ext=openssl,psych,+
-> make -j 12

BUILD FAILED (macOS 14.5 on x86_64 using ruby-build 20240727)

You can inspect the build directory at /var/folders/10/2qd53y5s0d91d1kt_mldyx5r0000gq/T/ruby-build.20240731175446.72608.gxR1Z7
See the full build log at /var/folders/10/2qd53y5s0d91d1kt_mldyx5r0000gq/T/ruby-build.20240731175446.72608.log
Error: 
   0: ~/Library/Caches/mise/ruby/ruby-build/bin/ruby-build exited with non-zero status: exit code 1

And in the log file
readline.c:1903:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
                                    rl_username_completion_function);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    rl_username_completion_function

I tried variations of mise install to force the arm64 architecture, since this is what I suspect is causing the issue. arch --arm64 mise install ruby@3.2.1 and ARCH=arm64 mise install ruby@3.2.1 doesn't change a thing.
Can someone guess what's happening ?

This solution worked for me.
MacOS 14.5, MacBook Pro M1.

brew install ruby
brew link --overwrite ruby --force
You will see a terminal warning:


Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: ruby If
you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:   echo 'export
PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
For compilers to find ruby you may need to set:   export
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"   export
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
For pkg-config to find ruby you may need to set:   export
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"


Paste in terminal: echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

If you are using zsh, you may need additional steps:
4.1. Configure environment variables for compilers:
echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"' >> ~/.zshrc

echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"' >> ~/.zshrc

4.2. Configure the environment variable for pkg-config:
echo 'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"' >> ~/.zshrc


Reload your terminal.

Check ruby version: ruby -v


I hope you'll see output ruby 3.3.4 or newer.
Hope it helps!
